# Obtaining the maximum height of a font

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fonts, rendering

So I have an NSFont, and I want to get the maximum dimensions for any characters, ie. the pitch and letter height.  [font maximumAdvancement] seems to return an NSSize of {pitch, 0}, so that's not helping.  Bounding rect doesn't seem to work either, and the suggestion from [jwz's similar question](http://jwz.livejournal.com/628853.html) of creating a bezier path, appending a glyph and getting the bounding rectange is also giving me back {0, 0}.  What gives here?

**UPDATE**: The code I'm using to get the bezier size is this:

```
NSBezierPath *bezier = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
NSGlyph g;
{
    NSTextStorage *ts = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString:@" "];
    [ts setFont:font];
    NSLayoutManager *lm = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    NSTextContainer *tc = [[NSTextContainer alloc] init];
    [lm addTextContainer:tc];
    [tc release]; // lm retains tc
    [ts addLayoutManager:lm];
    [lm release]; // ts retains lm
    g = [lm glyphAtIndex:0];
    [ts release];
}
NSPoint pt = {0.0f};
[bezier moveToPoint:pt];
[bezier appendBezierPathWithGlyph:g inFont:font];
NSRect bounds = [bezier bounds];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The glyph for the space character doesn't have any subpaths, so of course its bounds have size `NSZeroSize`. Try `-[NSFont boundingRectForFont]` instead.